# calculated property in EF 6 Database first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When I do

```
public string RequestIDFormated { get; set; }
```

I see the name RequestIDFormated in the output with null value;

When I replace it for

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
```

or

```
[global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
```

And

```
    public string RequestIDFormated
    {
        get
        {
            return RecordCreateDatetime.Year.ToString();
        }
        private set { /* needed for EF */ }
    }
```

it does not even show in the output
I am using EF 6.1.3

Comment: well, if you are using database-first, manual changes to the context code are not a good idea... What is expected value of `RequestIDFormated`. Give us more information about your problem

Comment: The expected value is just a concatenation of some existing values in the same class. Nothing fancy. Do you have a better way to show items based on other items from the DB?

Answer (score 1):

If you were using code-first, you could create a `NotMapped` property to return the concatenation of the values. Like this:

```
[NotMapped]
public string SomeProperty 
{
   get { return Property1 + Property2; } 
}
```

However, you are using database-first, so I think the better way is using a `partial class` that contains your property (it must be in the same namespace and assembly as generated part). Like this:

```
public partial class YourEntntiy
{
     public string MyNewProperty { get { return Property1 + Property2; } }
}
```

Comment: [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()] 
        public string RequestIDFormated
        {
            get
            {
                return RecordCreateDatetime.Year.ToString();
            }
            set { /* needed for EF */ }
        } did the trick! just took away the sugested "Private" Thank you all

Comment: Ok, but it is not necessary.